# About Fourier transform and complex conjugate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

why this passage is correct ?
\begin{equation*}
\mathscr{F}[h(-\tau)] = H^*(f),
\end{equation*}
when $h(\tau)$ is a real function of real variable $\tau$, and $H^*(f)$ is the complex conjugate of $\mathscr{F}[h(\tau)]=H(f)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a change of variable:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(-\tau)\,e^{i\tau t}\,d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)\,e^{-i\tau t}\,d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)\,\overline{e^{i\tau t}}\,d\tau=\overline{\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)\,e^{i\tau t}\,d\tau}
$$
because $h$ is real valued.